# Why the death probability of this $3$ is $q$, but not $1-(1-q)^3$?

Tags: variance, actuarial-science

A company offers a group insurance with $b$ payable in the event of the travel accident. The question states that $q$ is the probability of death by travel accident for an individual.
In a certain group of $100$ lives, the independence assumption fails because three specific individuals always travel together. If one dies in an accident, all three are assumed to die. Determine the Variance of this insurance.

For each insured，

$$V(X)=b^2q(1-q)\; .$$

My answer is to segregate the $100$ into two parts.
For the $97$, the variance is $97 V(X)=97 b^2 q(1-q)$;
For the specific three, this is a Bernoulli distribution with $\text{Pr}(Y=3b)=1-(1-q)^3$. By Bernoulli shortcut, 
$$V(Y)= (3b)^2 (1-q)^3 (1-(1-q)^3)\; .$$

Then

$$97 V(X)+V(Y)=97 b^2 q(1-q)+(3b)^2 (1-q)^3 (1-(1-q)^3) \; .$$

But the correct answer states that the variance of the $3$ is $V(3X)=3^2 b^2 q(1-q)$. That means the specific $3$ is a Bernoulli distribution with $\text{Pr}(Y=3b)=q$.

I don't know why the death probability of this $3$ is $q$, but not $1-(1-q)^3$.

Comment: $P(Y=3b)$ is the probability that all of them die. But that is the probability that just one of them dies, because if one dies then they all die. Hence $P(Y=3b)=q$. You are trying to treat them as if they are independent, but they are explicitly dependent.

Comment: If you take $\mathbb P(Y=3b)=q$ and $\mathbb P(Y=0)=1-q$, you will get $\mathbb E[Y]=3bq$ as expected.  Your formulation does not give that, or gives other values of $Y$ a non-zero probability

Comment: @David if the 3 always travel together, by means in one vehicle together, so the probability of accident is always just from one person, perhaps the driver..? Which is $q$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, this was the first time i post.

Comment: @kccu You are right! These three men's states are dependent, and could not be treated independently. So my answer is wrong when I tried to get the probability that they are all dead by multiply the probability q separately. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arief Thanks! Your explanation is much easier to understand!